# EventBridge rule is not getting triggered via custom event pattern of parameter store

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I have created one event bridge with below custom event pattern of updating value of SSM parameter store. when I update the value rule is not getting triggered. Anything i am missing ?

```
{
  "version": ["0"],
  "id": ["80e9b391-6a93-413c-839a-453b528083af"],
  "source": ["aws.ssm"],
  "detail-type": ["Parameter Store Change"],
  "account": ["647587844964"],
  "time": ["2017-05-22T16:44:48Z"],
  "region": ["us-east-1"],
  "resources": ["arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:647587844964:parameter/bfom_date"],
  "detail": {
    "operation": ["Update"],
    "name": ["bfom_date"],
    "type": ["String"],
    "description": ["Sample Parameter"]
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you triggering with this change? What is your target? An sns/lambda etc?

Comment: Step function but i think that does not matter as rule itself is not triggering based on event pattern

Comment: You need to have `{
  "source": ["aws.ssm"],
  "detail-type": ["Parameter Store Change"]
}` as event.

Comment: You cannot get the change with the above event type as the event which will be triggered when you make any change will be different.